# How to remove a listener in 0MQ (node.js library)?

Tags: node.js, zeromq

Tried to google it or find it in the [docs](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node) with no success.

How to replace the callback for incoming messages from

```
socket.on ('message', function () { /* code 1 */ })
```

to

```
socket.on ('message', function () { /* code 2 */ })
```

as I noticed that this *adds up* the callbacks.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that zmq (for node.js) inherits from `EventEmitter` [(doc here)](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html).   (`util.inherits(Socket,EventEmitter)` in `zmq/lib/index.js`)

Hence,

1. `emitter.addListener(event, listener)`is an alias for `emitter.on(event, listener).`
2. You can use `emitter.removeListener(event, listener)`to
   remove a listener.
3. Or use `emitter.once (event, listener)` to install a listener "one use

emitter.once(event, listener)